# How can commands be run from D?

Tags: command, d

So, I'm coming from Java and I'd like to use a small D script to start a server with a bunch of parameters. So, instead of typing

> java -someargs... -jar really-long-jar-name.jar

I would like to just click on the executable.

Is there any equivalent to [Runtime#exec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Runtime.html#exec(java.lang.String)) in D?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `std.process.executeShell` or `std.process.execute` to achieve this:

```d
import std.process : executeShell;
auto res = executeShell("java -jar my_program.jar");
if(res.status != 0)
{
    ...
}
```